# How to use a .h file without header guards multiple times

Tags: c

Currently I have a .h file provided by a professor that I'm not allowed to modify.  I have to use structures and implement the methods from the given .h file but it doesn't have header guards.  I want to write a file to test the methods but am running into a typedef redefinition error when trying to include the .h file in multiple locations.

I could write all the tests in the corresponding .c file and delete them later, but it would make the file rather big and I would like to use these tests again/modify them in the future as the project builds on itself.

I could also make a copy of the .h and include header guards, test it, then change it back before turning it in.  I'm somewhat new to C and was curious if there was a simpler solution or a more efficient way of doing this without modifying the .h file.  Thanks.

Comment: I guess you could create a wrapper .h file with header guards that includes the .h file from your professor. Then include the wrapper file in the rest of your project.

Comment: It's worth understanding why the header file is being included multiple times. You may be structuring your code incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either wrap it with a second header `guarded_header.h` that has the guards:

```
#ifndef GUARDED_HEADER_H
#define GUARDED_HEADER_H
#include "unguarded_header.h"
#endif
```

Then in your source:

```
#include "guarded_header.h"
```

or you could just inline the above around each point of inclusion. I like the wrapping better, but if the original header already is known to define one or more macros, you can do it inline easily as:

```
#ifndef SOMETHING_UNGUARDED_HEADER_DEFINES
#include "unguarded_header.h"
#endif
```